# Colocar un bottomNavigationBar flotante sobre AppBar en Flutter

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter, dart

estoy diseñando una app en Flutter, en la cuál quiero colocar un menú con botones que esté flotando o sobre el AppBar, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen, la cual es solo un mockup, de tal manera que la mitad de la altura esté sobre el `bottom` del `AppBar` y la mitad inferior quedé fuera del AppBar y encima del body:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este código:

```
Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: styles.fondo,
            title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'lib/Resources/images/x_circulo.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(30),
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    'lib/Resources/images/x_letras.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(35),
                  ),
                ]
            ),
            actions: appBar(),
            bottom:PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size(_deviceSize.width,70),
                child: BottomBar(),
            ),
           ),
          drawer: HomeDrawer(),
          //TODO: Basado en Flutter-ecommerce
          body: HomePage(),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(), //TODO: basado en Shopx-master
        ),
```

Pero lamentablemente no me es posible sobreponerlo sobre el margen inferior del AppBar, he intentado usar un stack en el body, pero no funciona ya que solo puedo moverlo sobre el body, intenté ponerlo como un `bottomNavigationBar` pero obviamente solo se puede abajo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes personalizar tu `AppBar` implementando la clase `PreferredSize`, luego podrías ayudarte de `Stack` para darle el efecto de que está encima.

Aquí te preparé un ejemplo básico :

```dart
class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: MyCustomAppBar(
        height: kToolbarHeight * 2,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          title: Text("hello world"),
        ),
        bottomWidget: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.add),
              Icon(Icons.add_alert),
              Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSize {
  final AppBar appBar;
  final Widget bottomWidget;
  final double height;

  const MyCustomAppBar({
    Key key,
    this.appBar,
    this.bottomWidget,
    this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: height,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: appBar,
            height: height / 1.2,
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 30,
            right: 30,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 10,
              child: bottomWidget,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget get child => this;

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);
}
```

Te dejo un post que escribí hace un tiempo: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-increase-the-power-of-your-appbar-sliverappbar-c4f67c4e076f

Comment: Gracias, funcionó como debía, pero hay un detalle, no es responsivo, o no se ve igual en pantallas de distintas resoluciones, en un momento publicaré el detalle aquí.

Comment: Usa MediaQuery para no poner valores en duros sino en base a porcentajes : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3WrA4zAaPw